# ajaxComplete, XMLHttpRequest is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-1.9

I have a global `ajaxComplete` handler:

```
 $('body').ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {           
        if (request.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1') {
            alert("unauthorized");                
        };
    });
```

The problem in that the `request` always in undefined, is filled only `event`.
Can you explain me why?

Example of ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        data: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (content) {           
            $('#modal').html(content);
            $('#modal').modal();           
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
From the API docs (Thanks to Austin Mullins):
**As of jQuery 1.8, however, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document.**

I have change my code to this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {            
        if (request.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1') {
            alert("unauthorized");               
        };
    });
```

But now I get the error:

```
TypeError: document.createDocumentFragment is not a function    
safeFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(); (jquery-1.9.0.js (line 5800))
```

Browser is Firefox 19.0.2

**SOLUTION:**
The problem was in the Jquery version 1.9.0. I have updated to 1.9.1 and the error is gone. Thanks to Boaz.

Comment: From [the API docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/): >Note: As of jQuery 1.8, however, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document.

Comment: @AustinMullins: I have change to document, but now I get the error `TypeError: document.createDocumentFragment is not a function`

Comment: How did you change it? It should be `$(document).ajaxComplete()`.

Comment: @AustinMullins: yes, I make it like that.

Comment: in the handler callback can you add `console.log(arguments)` and check the console

Comment: @ArunPJohny: nothing happens, breakpoint not work also. It looks as if the error occurs first.

Comment: Just to make sure - you mean the `success` handler is not executed either?

Comment: the console will indicate which file and line threw that error

Comment: @Boaz: no, `success` is executed. I mean `ajaxComplete` handler not executed at all.

Comment: @user348173 Have you tried the `.getResponseHeader()` method of the `xhr` object returned to the `success` object?

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: can you remove the success handler from the ajax call and test it once

Comment: @Boaz: I tryed, xhr object is returned in the `success`. all fine - status 200. `getResponseHeader` works also.

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP states Firefox 19.0.2

Comment: @user348173 I think the problem is in the success handler, can you remove the dom manipulation code from the success handler and try again

Comment: It seems you're using jQuery `1.9.0`. There were several AJAX-related bugfixes in jQuery `1.9.1`. Try using the latest jQuery release, just to rule this out as the cause.

Comment: @Boaz: Thank you. I have update the jquery to the last version and the error is gone

Comment: No problem. Posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Boaz, we do not need *three* tags to discuss issues in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @Charles Considering that jQuery 1.9 is a major release that introduced numerous core changes, I thought it'll be helpful to distinct between 1.9.0 and 1.9.1 which introduced many bugfixes to problems naturally caused by such a major release. But I yield to your judgement, if you don't believe it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your edits, it seems you're using `jQuery 1.9.0`. There were several [AJAX-related bugfixes in `jQuery 1.9.1`](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/). Try using the latest jQuery release.